# Windows Server 2003 Not Recognizing Memory

Tags: windows-server-2003, memory, low-memory

I have a Dell Power Edge 1850, running Windows 2k3 x86. It has 4 GB of RAM (8 total sticks of 512MB, which I have tried re-seating, and completely replaced with new memory) however this is what I am seeing whenever I look at the Task Manager.

[image: Memory Usage]

What is going on here? It appears that it is running with close to 1 GB of RAM but only has 261 MB of physical memory? Does the indicator on the left include the physical memory + the available PF? Is there anything I can do to get windows to recognize the rest of the memory if possible?

Thank you in advance.

**Edit**:
Should have said 6 total sticks of 512MB. With a total of 3072MB.

Comment: What's about ram from bios?

Comment: Which PE1850 is this?  The Dell [documentation for the PE1850](http://support.dell.com/support/edocs/systems/pe1850/en/it/r1712c60.htm#wp1081461) indicate only 6 slots.

Comment: @jscott, my mistake you are correct. 6 slots. So I have 6x 512Mb should be equal to 3072Mb. I ran the tool that @Phil had indicated below, and it does show all 6 sticks at 512Mb.

Answer (score 7):

In some Dell systems, there is a BIOS option for "OS Install Mode". This limits the server to 256MB of physical RAM if it is enabled.

Comment: +1 for that being a very logical reason. Half a stick is an odd size otherwise - sticks normally fail TOTALLY. Worth a check.

Answer (score 1):

When you boot, you should be shown how much memory the server can "see" installed.

Also, you can use a tool such as http://www.cpuid.com/ to check if the OS can see the sticks of memory installed.

If either of these don't show 8 x 512Mb then I suspect some of the memory is duff.

If all 8 sticks show up then its likely that the OS itself isn't allowing you access to it all.  I know that on Windows XP we would only see about 3.4GB with 4 x 1GB installed, not sure about Windows server though

Comment: I was incorrect about the number of slots I had 6x 512 Mb. I ran the tool you suggested and it is showing all of the sticks that I suspect.

Answer (score 0):

Defective hardware (Motherboard?) or incompatible bios (does not olike the memory). Point. 261mb memory is less than one stick. SHould not be like that.

Answer (score 0):

Try to boot your PE1850 with [DELL diagnostic CD](http://support.dell.com/support/downloads/format.aspx?c=us&l=en&s=gen&SystemID=XPS_M1210&os=LE30&osl=FR&deviceid=3841&typecnt=1&libid=13&releaseid=R133063&vercnt=2).